# Do unique $n^{th}$ roots commute in groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $g \in G$. Call $k$ an $n^{th}$ root of $g$ if $k \in G$, $k^n = g$.

Suppose that $g,h \in G$ and $g$ has an unique $n^{th}$ root, which will be denoted by $g^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

If $gh = hg$, is it true that $g^{\frac{1}{n}}h=hg^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

For some reason, this seems quite plausible to me, and I can't find a simple counterexample. Note that if $g=e$ (id. element), then any unique $n^{th}$ root must be $e$, since $e$ will always be an $n^{th}$ root of itself, so this special case will not provide any counterexamples.

Comment: Are you missing exponents on the $h$s?

Comment: @Randall I don't think so.

Comment: The situation with unique $n$'th roots seems implausible to me. Intuitively, there must be $n$ such roots. Do you have an example of a group in which a non-idenity element has exactly one $n$'th root for some $n > 1$?

Comment: @Vincent what are the square roots of $2$ in $(\mathbb{Z},+)$? If $g$ has finite order then your intuiting is right, there are at least $n$ such roots, but that breaks down if $g$ has infinite order because taking powers of $k$ never "wraps back round" to $g$.

Comment: Right, I forgot about infinite groups. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidSheard I am slightly confused. Suppose $n = |G|$, where $G$ is a finite group. Then, if $g \neq e$, $g$ has no $n$th roots due to Lagrange. Please could you clarify what you meant?

Comment: @Vincent $G = D_6$, the element $r$ has the unique square-root $r^2$. Of course, the result in the question does not say much here because $r^2$ is in the span of $r$, but still, this demonstrates that even elements in finite groups can have unique $n$th roots.

Comment: To your first comment, I wasn't saying that every element has an $n$th root for every $n$. I was saying that if an element has an $n$th root, say $k$, and it has finite order, say $m$, then it has (at least) $n$ many $n$th roots. These are $k^{im+1}$ for $0\le i\le n-1$. You can easily check that, since $k$ has order $nm$, we get $(k^{im+1})^n=(k^{nm})^ik^n=ek^n=g$.

Comment: @DavidSheard This is not true because the $k^{im+1}$ are not necessarily distinct for all $i$. Please see my example with $D_6$ in the reply to Vincent.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment. Is $r$ a reflection? In this case $r^2=e$ is not a square root of $r$. If $r$ is a rotation, what angle do you mean it to be a rotation through?

Comment: @DavidSheard By $r$, I refer to rotation by $2 \pi / 3$. I denote the reflection element by $s$. You can verify the counterexample I've given by finding a Cayley table for $D_6$. (To be absolutely clear, I also use the notation $D_{2n}$ to refer to the symmetries of a regular $n$-gon, so the equilateral triangle in this case.)

Comment: You are quite right, so you can have uniqueness in both the finite and infinite case. I was being quite cavalier and not worrying to check that incidental remark before I made. In some circumstances what I said is true. I think a sufficient condition is that there is an injection $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}=\langle a\rangle$ into your group for some $m>1$ such that $a\mapsto k$ and $a^n\mapsto g$...or something like that

Comment: @DavidSheard Given that $g$ has finite order $k$, I believe I have shown that there is only a unique $n$th root if and only if $k,n$ are coprime, with this $n$th root in the span of $g$. The argument is relatively simple; you can probably guess the approach from the statement. Thus, this result is indeed trivial in finite groups. I wonder if there are any non-trivial implications (for non-abelian groups) for elements of infinite order. I haven't met many non-abelian infinite groups so far.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Notice that
$$
  (h^{-1}g^{\frac{1}{n}}h)^n = h^{-1}gh = g,
  $$
so
$h^{-1}g^{\frac{1}{n}}h= g^{\frac{1}{n}}$ by uniqueness.

Comment: I was conjugating by the wrong element. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome!